# NameError: name 'save' is not defined

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Скопировала пример кода и решила его проверить, но выдало ошибку и я не знаю, как ее решить.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = 1.
x = np.arange(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 0.2)
y = np.sin(x) * np.cos(x)
# Уравнение кардиойды
xz = a*(2*np.cos(x) - np.cos(2*x))
yz = a*(2*np.sin(x) - np.sin(2*x))

label = ['aitoff', 'hammer', 'lambert', 'mollweide', 'polar', 'rectilinear']

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))

for i in range(len(label)):

    ax = fig.add_subplot(231+i, projection=label[i])
    ax.plot(xz, yz)
    ax.set_title(label[i], color='r')
    ax.grid(True)

plt.tight_layout()

save('pic_11_1_2', fmt='png')
save('pic_11_1_2', fmt='pdf')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Появилась новая ошибка AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'save'

Comment: Потому что matplotlib.pyplot не умеет в `save`, он умеет в `savefig`. Обратите внимание на ответ ниже.

Answer (score 4):

Замените:

```
save('pic_11_1_2', fmt='png')
save('pic_11_1_2', fmt='pdf')
```

на:

```
plt.savefig('pic_11_1_2.png')
plt.savefig('pic_11_1_2.pdf')
```